# Subtype data is lost when reaching controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'll write this as very simple as the actual fixing is less important than the actual designy bit I don't understand.
It seems that once my *@RequestBody* hits the *@Controller*, information on `subtype` is lost.

Assuming we have:

```
class A{
    String foo;
}
class B extends A{
    String bar;
}
```

Then another class that combines them (`{A,B,B,A}`)in what will become a request body:

```
class Body{
    List<A> list;
}
```

When sending the request with *ProducerTemplate* from camel there are two outcomes. Camel will take care of routing.

1. If running everything in the same process, a method with signature `method(Body b)` will correctly keep the information in the subtype. So a `(B)b.getList().get{1}` (get the second element, which was a B and cast it) will be correct.
2. When switching the route to a stub (Spring Boot) on a different process on localhost and sending the exact same data, the same method signature (`method(@RequestBody Body b`) will somehow forget information about Body, to the point that `(B)b.getList().get{1}` will get a cast exception.

Why is this happening? The *ProducerTemplate* takes in the same data and sends it to methods with the same signature which have access to the same object types. 
The only difference is that one is running in the same process with the client sending the request, while the other is running on localhost on a different port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to move forward was to basically change the `Body` to have `List<Object>` instead of `List<A>` and then probe the Object to see what type it actually is and cast it to that.

Because the actual problem was a JSON being serialized and then deserialized, the field itself was a changed from `List<A>` to `List<HashMap<String,Object>>`